# Cannot connect to local SSH server - bad file number

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I have an Odroid XU4 with Ubuntu 14.04 server on it.

I installed the ssh server with `apt-get install openssh-server`. I got the local IP with `hostname -I`, which is `192.168.0.186`, I generated a random port number: `61354`. I created a file `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys` and appended the public key of the client machine: `cat /media/stick/id_rsa.pub >> /etc/ssh/authorized_keys`. After that I overrode the config file with `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I set it to `PasswordAuthentication no`, `ListenAddress 192.168.0.186`, `Port 61354`, `AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorized_keys`. After that I rebooted the machine.

I tried to access it with SSH using `ssh 192.168.0.186 -p 61354` on the client without success: `ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.186 port 61354: Bad file number`, which is far from a verbose error message. I successfully `ping 192.168.0.186`, so the IP is okay. How to fix this?

edit:

```
$ ssh -vvv -p 61354 192.168.0.186
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/inf3rno/.ssh/config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.186 [192.168.0.186] port 61354.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.186 port 61354: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.186 port 61354: Bad file number
```

On the server I tried `ps aux | grep sshd`, according to it the ssh server is running. So probably there is a firewall, which prevents the client to connect to the server. I don't know what exactly is in the op system image I installed from here: http://odroid.in/ubuntu_14.04lts/ . I try to find out whether I have a firewall or not. (According to a forum there is no firewall installed.)

I checked with `nmap`

```
[inf3rno@inf3rno ~]$ sudo nmap -sS 192.168.0.186 -p 61354
[sudo] password for inf3rno: 
Starting Nmap 7.00 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-02-07 15:22 CET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.186
Host is up (0.0041s latency).
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
61354/tcp closed unknown
MAC Address: 00:1E:06:30:1E:CE (Wibrain)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.12 seconds
```

and `traceroute`

```
traceroute to 192.168.0.186 (192.168.0.186), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets 1 192.168.0.186 (192.168.0.186) 5.833 ms 5.773 ms 8.347 ms
```

I tried a simple socket server using this tutorial: http://www.binarytides.com/netcat-tutorial-for-beginners/

```
$ nc -l -v 1234 # starting the socket server
$ telnet localhost 1234 # client connection: ok
$ telnet 192.168.0.186 1234 # client connection: refused
```

So this is clearly network related, and probably I have to check the modem settings. I tried this out on another machine with Fedora with the same results.

**conclusion**

It turned out this is something network related. Most probably there is no firewall installed on the machine, so this is no firewall related issue. I have the same on a Fedora 23 install. I think this is something general in the network, and probably caused by the new modem I got. I try to check the modem settings, maybe I find the root of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH error: “Connect to host: Bad file number”](http://superuser.com/questions/988515/ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number)

Comment: `sudo iptables -S` will list active `iptables` rules.

Comment: @Jakuje There is neither `iptables` nor `ufw` installed on the server (and the client). According to a forum post the operation system image I installed comes without firewall by default.

Comment: What about `ncat 192.168.0.186 61354`? Can you give it a try with the service on standard port?

Comment: @Jakuje Connection refused, if I have to use it on the client...

Comment: @Jakuje This is clearly network related. I tried with a socket server and telnet. From localhost it is ok, by using the local IP it is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ssh` command as described in manual page:

```
ssh -p 61354 192.168.0.186
```

the port number MUST be before the hostname/IP, otherwise it might not be honoured.

To the actual error, the `connect` function is blocked, as described in the question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number). You need to open the port on firewall on the way (`traceroute 192.168.0.186`), or use some opened port (if you don't run https server on the same machine, `443` should be open).

Comment: Still bad file number...

Comment: post to the edited question the whole output from `ssh -vvv -p 61354 192.168.0.186`

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: How can I find out whether I have firewall or not? According to a forum I read, there is no firewall in the os image I installed to the device.

Comment: I added note to find out what is on the way in your network. It looks more hardware fiirewall on network device (router?), not software on the end machine.

Comment: `traceroute to 192.168.0.186 (192.168.0.186), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.186 (192.168.0.186)  5.833 ms  5.773 ms  8.347 ms
` - only the modem is between the odroid and my pc.

Comment: so you have some rules in  `iptables` or something. Still not enoug information provided.

Comment: Then tell me pls how to provide enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the conclusion section in the question I managed to send data between machines with the socket server using the same commands. What I did before that is accessing the modem's admin page. It went through a first access process, like password change, etc. I did not change anything in the settings, but after that the communication worked properly. I am not sure whether I mistyped the commands or this first access procedure fixed it, does not really matter. The root of the problem was something else.

The SSH server still did not work after this part, so I started to play with the configuration.

> After that I overrode the config file with nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
>   I set it to PasswordAuthentication no, ListenAddress 192.168.0.186,
>   Port 61354, AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.

I removed the `ListenAddress` and `Port` from the config file. After that I got the `permission denied (public key)` message using the `ssh 192.168.0.186` command, so connection was established, but the authentication failed. So I still have work to do, but at least it connected.

At the end I removed the `AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorized_keys` too and moved the file to the default location `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and connected with `ssh root@192.168.0.186`. Now it works properly. :-)

Comment: Ports above 32000 are for client connections, better stay below with a service. To have a central directory for users' keys use:  AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u